# didReceiveLocalNotification not getting called when app is in the background on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

When I receive a local notification and tap on it, I want to be able to get information out of the notification.

If my app is in the foreground, didReceiveLocalNotification gets called like I would expect. When it is running in the background, the only delegate method that gets called is didBecomeActive on iOS 7. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not called either.

On iOS 6, didReceiveLocalNotification gets called when the app is running, but in the background.

Is there something I'm missing that changed in iOS 7?

Comment: While clicking of notification "didReceiveLocalNotification" must be called. 
Kindly share your code so its easy to track issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be simulator weirdness. It all worked fine when switching to a different computer.